# Issue storing user id's in a json file

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So what I'm trying to do is to store user id's and add their score when they do a command. But the issue I'm getting is the user gets logged twice and it doesn't add the score. This is what happens in the json file:

```
{"272356126391238536": {"experience": 1}, "272356126391238536": {"experience": 1}}
```

This is a part of my code that defines the update and add:

```
async def update(amount, user):
   if not user.id in amount:
       amount[user.id] = {}
       amount[user.id]['experience'] = 0

async def add(amount, user, exp):
amount[user.id]['experience'] += exp
```

This is the part in the command that the score updates from:

```
await update(buffer, ctx.message.author)
await add(buffer, ctx.message.author, 1)
```

When I change the ".id" to a ".name" It works fine but the issue with name is if a user changes his name his old score will be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use a ctx variable, so:

```
async def update(ctx, amount):
   if not str(ctx.message.author.id) in amount:
       amount[str(ctx.message.author.id)] = {}
       amount[str(ctx.message.author.id)]['experience'] = 0

async def add(amount, user : discord.Member, exp):
    amount[user.id]['experience'] += exp
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't use the exact code but I only needed to convert the ids to strings and that solved it.